# Why AWS Lambda suggests to set up two subnets if VPC is configured?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

Is this because of the IP availability?

I've always thought that creating a single huge subnet instead of creating two with the same size, is exactly the same. I haven't experienced any perfomance issues by doing this, but I haven't found anything in the docs to confirm that this is a valid way.

Why AWS Lambda suggests to configure these two subnets? is there a technical reason for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need emphasis on ".. subnets **across different Availability Zones** .."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not "only" for performance, it is for high availability(more fault-tolerant) according to [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

> It's a best practice to create multiple private subnets across different Availability Zones for redundancy and so that Lambda can ensure high availability for your function.

[Resilience documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/security-resilience.html)

Comment: Further: An AWS Lambda function can be instantiated and attached to any of the configured subnets. Therefore, if there is a failure in an Availability Zone, then the Lambda function can continue to be used in a remaining AZ. This is because subnets are associated with a specific AZ. The basic concept of High Availability is "have more than one of something" and put them in different AZs.